# Using Nest JS Validation Pipe and class-transformer to get kebab-case query params

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm trying to make use of Nest JS Validation Pipe to auto transform and validate my GET Request Query Params

e.g

`{{url}}/path?param-one=value&param-two=value`

On `app.module.ts`, I have the following code to set global validation pipe

```
    app.useGlobalPipes(
      new ValidationPipe({
        transform: true,
        whitelist: true,
        forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      }),
    );
```

And I have a DTO to do the validation

```
class MyValidationDto {
   @IsString()
   paramOne: string

   @IsString()
   paramTwo: string
}
```

And in my controller, I make use of the `MyValidationDto` class

```
class MyController {
   ... stuff

   @Get('/path')
   async myFunction (Query() queryParams: MyValidationDto) { ...code }
}
```

However, I'm not sure where to go to in order to parse the kebab case query keys `param-one` and `param-two` to the camelCase class properties `paramOne` and `paramTwo` in the validation DTO

I've tried looking at Nest JS doc, `class-validator` doc and `class-transformer` doc, as well as search the highs and lows of internet to no luck. This should be a fairly common case so not sure where I'm going wrong here

Unless this is not possible and I should be using the `Query()` decorator instead. Please advise :pray:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; There's no native method from NestJS or class-validator to do this for now (a similar [feature request is still open on CT repo](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/286)).

However, there are a couple of workarounds:

You can use [`@Expose()`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#exposing-properties-with-different-names) but you still need to customize your error message as the new exposed name won't be passed to the context:

```
export class SomeDTO {
  @IsString()
  @Expose({ name: 'my-name' })
  myName: string;
  ..
```

Or you can create a [NestJS pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) that normalizes your query params before they hit your controller.

For example, create a new pipe:

```
@Injectable()
export class NormalizeQueryParamsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: RestaurantDTO, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const normalizedQueryParams = {
      ...value,
      name: value['my-name'],
    };

    delete normalizedQueryParams['my-name'];
    return normalizedQueryParams;
  }
}
```

Of course, you may do better than renaming attributes manually and using an approach like [this](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/286#issuecomment-773564566) combined with [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator): Basically use class validator methods combined with a [transformer that converts](https://github.com/sindresorhus/camelcase-keys) your kebab-case keys to camelcase (e.g `plainToClass(camelcaseKeys(value), MyValidationDto)`)

This transforms your `'my-name'` to `myName`, and you want to have this before the global validation pipe:

```
// in main.ts:

app.useGlobalPipes(new NormalizeQueryParamsPipe());
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());

// or: app.useGlobalPipes(new NormalizeQueryParamsPipe(), new ValidationPipe());
```

In case you are not using a global validation pipe, you can just use [`@UsePipes()`](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) in your controller:

```
@Get()
@UsePipes(new NormalizeQueryParamsPipe())
async getAll() {
 ..
```

Comment: Thank you for this! As there is no direct way to do this, and this seems to be the least boilerplate-y solution, I've decided to go for this approach!